# Queue size exceeds from configured max queue capacity in ThreadPoolTaskExecutor used in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

Please Look at this below piece of code:

```
@Autowired  
private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor;  
  
@PostConstruct
public void setupTaskExecutor() {
    this.executor.setCorePoolSize(getExecutorCorePoolSize());
    this.executor.setMaxPoolSize(getExecutorMaxPoolSize());
    this.executor.setQueueCapacity(getExecutorMaxQueueCapacity());
}  
  
public ZoneDetail getZoneDetails(ConfigRequest configRequest) {

    LOGGER.debug("QueueSize = {}", executor.getThreadPoolExecutor().getQueue().size());
    LOGGER.debug("PoolSize = {}", executor.getPoolSize());      

    Future<ZoneDetail> future = executor.submit(() -> {
        return getPrimaryProvider(context).getZoneDetails(context, 
        configRequest);
    });

    try {
        ZoneDetail zoneDetail = future.get(getPrimaryProviderTimeout(),
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) { 
        // fetch data from secondary provider
    }
        
}
```

My configured values are
**core-pool-size=4

max-pool-size=16

max-queue-capacity=5**

I run a PT using SoapUI with following parameters,

```
Threads: 20  Strategy: Simple Test Delay: 0 Limit: 5 seconds
```

i.e. I am hitting 20 Threads at a time for 5 seconds.

In the console, I see **QueueSize = 15** i.e. my queue size exceeds the configured max queue capacity 5. And **PoolSize = 4** i.e. my pool size never exceeds core pool size since extra threads are going into queue.

**Note:** I am hitting a REST API that calls getZoneDetails() method

**How is it happening? What am I doing wrong ?**

Comment: Are you sure that you are configuring the right ThreadPoolExecutor since you can have have plenty.

Comment: @M.Mas. What do you mean by right ThreadPoolExecutor ? I'm using `import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor ;`

Comment: Your tasks are submitted explicitly using the autowired ThreadPoolExecutor ?

Comment: I can not understand what are the methods `getExecutorCorePoolSize` and the two others.are they your methods, if so please write them down.

Comment: @Itaywazana those methods are getter methods of fields that read from properties file.  `@ConfigurationProperties` is there at class level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- I don't think your setup is correct. You are autowiring `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` and it means it would have been already initialised the `ThreadPoolExecutor` with `QueueCapacity` of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and created a queue with that capacity. So whatever you do in `setupTaskExecutor()` is not going to take effect.
- Instead do the following in one go

```
    @Bean(name = "myThreadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public Executor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = 
                                             new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(getExecutorCorePoolSize());
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(getExecutorMaxPoolSize());
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(getExecutorMaxQueueCapacity());
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.initialize();
        return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
    }
```

- If you add `LOGGER.debug("RemainingCapacity = {}", this.executor.getThreadPoolExecutor().getQueue().remainingCapacity())` as the last line of `setupTaskExecutor()`, it should confirm this answer
- And then use it

```
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myThreadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor;
```

Comment: Thanks. Yesterday I also realized the same problem. When we set `queueCapacity` after `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` is created, it doesn't get propagated into `ThreadPoolExecutor` initialized in `initializeExecutor` method. Feel like this is a bug.